# Collection Mapping

Tags: java, collections, dozer

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class A1 {
  List<B1> bList;
}

class B1 {
  Long id;
}

---

class A2 {
  List<Long> bList;
}
```

I want to map class A1 to A2 with Dozer, where A1.bList contains B1 objects and A2.bList contains only the IDs of the B1 objects.

How would the mapping look like?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try setting up a mapping for `Long` to `B1`. If I remember rightly this only works one way, I can't remember which way tho. Sorry, hope this helps.

Comment: can you eplain  how to set-up mapping between long and B1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dozer custom converter. [Dozer customer converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html)

An example:  (possible errors, didn't compile or test it)

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>A1</class-a>
  <class-b>A2</class-b>    
  <field custom-converter="converters.YourCustomConverter">
    <a>bList</a>
    <b>bList</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

The custom converter:

```
public class YourCustomConverter implements CustomConverter {

    public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class destClass, Class sourceClass) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (source instanceof List<?>) {
            List<?> list = ((List<?>) source);
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            if (list.get(0) instanceof B1) {
                List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();
                for (B1 b1 : list) {
                    longList.add(b1.getId());
                }
                return longList;
            } else (list.get(0) instanceof Long) {
                // do the inverse of the above
            } else {
                throw new MappingException("Wrong type ...");
            }
        } else {
            throw new MappingException("Converter YourCustomConverter used incorrectly. Arguments passed in were:"
                    + destination + " and " + source);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by overridding **toString()** method in **B1** and it would work.

Here's sample code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return new String(this.id);
}
```

And in your mapping do the following changes:

```
<field>
 <a>bList</a>
 <b>bList</b>
 <a-hint>B</a-hint>
 <b-hint>java.lang.Long<b-hint>
</field>
```

So,when dozer tries to bind B1, it will return its id as String and then dozer will perform an automatic conversion between String and Long.